# Is it possible and legal to access database through html pages?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-services

Some days ago I decided to develop a train timetable mobile application for NSW australia. After some research, I found out that they do not share their databases with public and they don't have any webservices. We pay them through tax to gather our information but they do not share those data with us. Anyway this is moral issue rather than technical programming issue.

Technical question is, in their website they have 15 train lines and for each of them I can see this:

[T1 North Shore Line timetable](http://www.sydneytrains.info/timetables/index.htm#landingPoint)

After opening the view-source page (HTML page) and minutes of looking at the html tables I realize for example information about one train station such as 'Berowra' is presented in this way:

```
<span class="hintText">Berowra</span></td><td>03:40</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>04:37</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>05:36</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>05:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>06:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>06:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>07:02</td><td>07:12</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>07:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>07:32</td><td>07:42</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>07:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>08:02</td><td>08:12</td><td>---</td><td>08:24</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>08:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>08:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>09:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>09:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>10:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>10:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>11:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>11:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>12:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>12:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>13:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>13:57</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>14:27</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>14:59</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>15:29</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>15:59</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>16:29</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>16:59</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>17:29</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>17:59</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>18:30</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>19:00</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>19:30</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>19:58</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>20:28</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>20:54</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>21:24</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>21:54</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>22:24</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>22:54</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>23:24</td><td>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</td></tr></table></span>
```

So I can create tables in MySQL database and fill them up with these data from html page easily by parsing html tags. In other word we can access any database by viewing html view-source page and parse those tags. Before writing program to parse these tags and transferring data from html page to MySQL database I wanted to make sure if anyone has had a similar experience before knows that if

1. Dose parsing view-source pages needs a permission?
2. Is there any library or template to parse these webpages instead of writing bunch of if else and string comparison?
3. Is there any written program to transfer data from html pages to database?
4. Is this idea to transport from html page is feasible or not?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal matters and abstract principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technical point of view, it's not too difficult to parse a html page in PHP, and extract required information via PHP's [XML manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

What you're looking to do is called [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), in case you want to do some further research.

However, at http://www.sydneytrains.info/general/copyright it says that:

> The material contained in this website, including logos, text, graphics and photographic images is without limitation, protected by copyright under the Copyright Act 1968 (Cth) and/or the Trade Marks Act 1995 (Cth). None of the material in this website may be dealt with in any way, including reproduced, altered or transmitted without prior written permission, except:
>
> where necessary for an incidental to viewing the material on this
> internet site via web browser;
>
> or as permitted under the Copyright Act
> 1968 (Cth) or other applicable laws.

Thus, you can't legally do this without asking for permission, unless permitted under the Copyright Act 1968 (Cth), of which I have no idea.

Comment: Also, just because they say it is protected, doesn't necessarily mean it is protected. As you (@Bernard) say, all 3 train services in NSW are state-owned entities, so there may be an argument to say that this data should be open source. This would require legal opinion however, and I'm not a lawyer.